# Droidparts ClearableEditText

Tags: android, android-view

I've implemented "ClearableEditText" which mostly relies on code from DroidParts.
The purpose is to have an `EditText` with a `Drawable` on the right corner (i.e. X button) in order to clear the text.

I am using a selector for the button resource which is essentially `DrawableRight`.
This works perfect but the only problem I have is with the button getting false pressed states from it's parent (the `EditText`).

To reproduce:

1. Run the project
2. Enter text in first `EditText`
3. Press anywhere inside the `EditText` where there's no text / drawable.

Result:
selector gets PRESSED state.

Thanks for any help

Comment: did you try setting `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to your `EditText`?

Comment: @deville that's not an attribute you can add to an `EditText` as far as I know, only for a `ViewGroup`.

Comment: Oh, you are surely right about that. Another option would be to set drawable manually instead of using selector.

Comment: @deville I thought about it, if you mean monitoring the touch events to a level where I can detect press event inside the drawable coordinates and change the drawable accordingly, then restore it back on ACTION_UP/ACTION_CANCEL -- that would be my last resort, but I was wondering if there is a more straightforward way to achieve what I'm after..

Comment: Do you have your EditText as a parent to the drawable? If so it might be better to separate them out onto a layout.  This should prevent the false presses.

Comment: @user1132959 I'd rather have one view to handle everything, and take advantage of this drawableLeft/Right feature. that's what I'm trying to do..

Comment: You can still keep your ClearableEditText as one view.  But inside of it you would have a layout which has the EditText then to the right of it a Drawable.  That's probably the easiest way to do it otherwise you may end up having to try to hack around and that can get ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to achieve what you're after is to set an `OnTouchListener` on the entire `EditText` and detect `ACTION_PRESS` within the `Drawable`'s coordinates, then replace the selector accordingly. If you don't want to use this technique you have to create a custom `View` which will consist of a layout that separates the two, i.e. `LinearLayout` with an `ImageView` and a `TextView` as it's children.

Cheers